# How can I call a function from one component to another? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instance, function-call

I'm working in react.js. I've created a component `Backend.jsx`. I want it to work as a service (like in angular) where I can send API requests. I want to call methods of `Backend` in some other components.

I called this backend service in component and try to send data and get it in `BackendService` using props.

But obviously this will not work.

**Here's my code**

In **Component**:

This will be called after form submit.

```
handleLoginSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.data);
    <BackendService onSendData = {this.state.data} />
}
```

In **BackendService**:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  }
    this.login(props)
}
login = (props) =>
{
    console.log('login', props);
};
```

Any suggestions how can I call this `login` method in `component`. Or any other suggestion to get component data in service.

Comment: you can call login method using **react ref**

Comment: you can achieve this with event emitter.

Comment: Can u show me some code guys? I'm new to react. Nagesh saurssaurav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

1.Component.js

```
class Componet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data:"this state contain data"
    }

    this.backendServiceRef = React.createRef(); // Using this ref you can access method and state of backendService component.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => {

          this.backendServiceRef.current.login()  

       }}>click</button>

        <BackendService ref={this.backendServiceRef} onSendData = {this.state.data}></BackendService>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Componet;
```

2.BackendService.js

```
class BackendService extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  login = (props) => {
    alert("login call")
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Backend service component
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer was helpful. But I don't want render function in ```backend```. Can u help me with this?